# Splitting a Dataframe into multiple sheets

Tags: python, pandas

I've have a dataset that I'm ingesting into python and making several transformations, however after all the code is done I'm trying to publish the output file to an excel file, however I want to split the file into multiple sheets, each sheet containing it's header, I've tried the following codes:

1: If I use an specific column to groupby it will yield the error that the sheet is too large (reason I want to split by 1M rows)

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        
for key,g in icms_data.groupby('New_Loc'):    
    g.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key, index=False, header=True)

writer.save()
print('done')
```

2: I've tried to go through every one million row but it takes way too long for the code to run and to create the excel file needed:

```
GROUP_LENGTH = 1000000

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')

for i in range(0, len(icms_data), GROUP_LENGTH):
    print(i)
    icms_data.iloc[i:i+GROUP_LENGTH,].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Row {}'.format(i), header= true)

writer.save()
print('done')
```

The file may have 3M or 4M or 2M depending on when it's download, is it possible to have a code that goes to the whole dataframe and split into 1M chunks and have those chunks saved into different sheets?

Comment: if your data is this large don't use excel, use `paruqet` or `feather` or even `.csv` with `gzip` compression. why do you need it in excel? Excel is no good for data bigger than 500k ish rows (even with that it will struggle) alternatively you can export your data straight into a db.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can slice the dataframe in a for loop and write the slices to sheets:

```
GROUP_LENGTH = 1000000 # set nr of rows to slice df

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
  for i in range(0, len(df), GROUP_LENGTH):
      df[i : i+GROUP_LENGTH].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Row {}'.format(i), index=False, header=True)
```

Comment: this code was running for way to long and I end kill the session :/

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use `dask` in stead of `pandas` with these amounts of data

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the total size of the dataframe as Excel has workbook size limits, but you can try something like;

```
GROUP_LENGTH = 1000000
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
number_of_chunks = math.ceil(len(df)/GROUP_LENGTH)
chunks = np.array_split(df,number_of_chunks)
sheet_number = 0
for chunk in chunks:
    chunk.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet_number)
    sheet_number+=1

writer.save()
```

Comment: interestingly the code was giving me an error as follow: NameError: name 'chunks' is not defined

Comment: @silentninja89 Double check your syntax and make sure you declared the chunks variable as in the example.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old but I was able to do it using [np.array_split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html)

```
count = 1
splits = np.array_splits(df, length)
for df in splits:
   df.to_excel(f'output {count}.xlsx', header=True, index=False)
   count += 1
```